# MainWindow.xib Does Not Show Up in Files Pane After Accidental Deletion

Tags: ios, xcode, svn

I am using XCode 4.0.2 and I accidentally deleted MainWindow.xib. I used SVN to revert it and I have seen that it is located inside an en.lproj directory. The problem is I can't make it show up on the left pane anymore.

What can I do to make it show up there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does the project compile and find the file successfully?  If not, have you tried dragging it from Finder into your left pane?  And choosing not to copy to directory (if it's already in the right folder in Finder)?